# How do I break a really long line into smaller lines of 64 characters each in vim?

Tags: vim, vi, macvim

I have a very long set of characters around 1000 characters long without any spaces in them. Can I break them neatly into rows of 64 characters each in vim. For example,

I want to convert a string like this:

```
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
```

to:

```
MIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQDOgwPQvZf9l3WY
A/+eMcjz+v/1aWrebfpVLCOMDPN/mvWpG5cufxirk9nmX1yqzeYoIyrXsJ2MfCL
didf3nZ6wmBkKXq8dk51fG7+NzuG15UWtsZSp4z2fbVMWhulcUtj39zXCPCqFqk
/St+Gc2SKZOOLi6TuvlsJAPGVS+shJJXeCZPBRiqEQhXZE7zsVrKFCM2tFZp1RL
E9TWB+LNYOYg6/KES+iVwjqY4CcVqKMA6frUC/7N/Q9U7pvJbZiMRh4ScdnyEzJ
MvcIJcItt/0piZCZyOaVIv15RVOG4b9E0BMgEEtOvVgD+tLqKus/fdWz/hdtyVj
DIlc5mzQnl98TAgMBAAECggEBAJnWpZ/5rOD/1F0jFWgOZEnEgKqcFj2Opf6O/A
gXmclEcZ7Ba/T6PzGJ2bgw8AJZkgvybrbw3dzKmNp6FkViyNV66KR99mvNDF3Oe
Ps105TCMA79i+am3sAGG/BbHjpliTXnlceVNIQQZJhv3QUQCCMmanZpEspyP1DE
7SJMqak6hh+irTx9n1Z+Eh8ma3hZ0vTpy5w96eWOk2NRGOMrUikEMApsBxI1W4H
krG3WI0MlWnLLv/DyGbIwiqp3Q2l39vKO/S5K3A8NVOuHbOvqHrP96g3a4srozu
34tzXIcghxwECNx5mpouw4/lo53Ybo8JiNcU8s8fEmY6ufLaL0BlkCgYEA7y3Y6
yIWPN04sK9jPZ/8hc6XzpelmFkc6d7kRDxTv3dWsWZAgos8a2zsKBmVFXJ7Aq2a
Nx+nmGPnYxr24Mu65NDfrd+rki4HxTqO0tkL9KI66y4F+yd796tkdqkLSyu5u9e
ci6hNaGeaJaX3es3Mq0J2i9hQ793XWXyv6mRh3dUCgYEA3QkHbhwd6KuE0AtI6P
1e9dBn7DQip8VuJjY78qbFAMVEwJsn/aBL5CbzScCiIs8/wsx30LgbLPmPbVd0k
fjrb9/eLKdej6EyZkLgrIUKBxSpg1f86TTCz0F3RUEiGBPtvFpJHfMVFjXGktUA
yBvJyDTZjSSq79h7IPb3j+lNdUcCgYBGGLK1HrVTuyXtKkm0etngQU7eXjVK8/r
0U72kfeWxfIEs1qHbYIEhnreLfQvjUDza6RQEScOtdsIOmo12Dl9Exi5339CBs/
nVBLds9e16Eb2gxUk9dTHwwQtdd2d27WautZ8MkxO0oIBdvklMdVohawYhMBFwa
xy8/jz0Pd0szQKBgEZ0jFPCzp3NnmYaUsFBkjVUmuulqq5DtlqjyvQLyJv4RXQH
gPXNVKOC7uXBa20hFrfnKQH0zWTGn7tAtz2YVKOyfkVJjFDIFyKVirwzJAEhyu6
86zcCxF4ABh6jJlT6dTsmpEvRohUUSxmen8MpaGZSwk3FNF+DZ6wYTM0olrIdAo
GBAKMc/LEIxgqwpFIzxIsFj4lSaGwIWFimMSq/9gd9R60/gncaBearSXrNwVBHP
qfZBFnGeLTiddD7F/x/LbcPip+Hj0/PFphAxWfPfgLrTl2cGf4975mJbny11WjD
+WucpB3YsXoOjo+z4rX0g4JmRuM0XDFy/ef11BMMQ2wjBZ54
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 6):

If calling external commands is ok you could use the [fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(Unix)) command:

```
fold -w64 file
```

To apply the command within vim, you could do a visual selection of your string and then:

```
:'<,'>!fold -w64 %
```

Or to apply the command to the current line:

```
:.!fold -w64 %
```

Without external command this could work:

```
:.s#.\{64\}#&\r#g
```

From the man page:

> An ampersand (`&`) appearing in the replacement is replaced by the string matching the RE

Comment: The last command `:.s#.\{64\}#&\r#g` would work the same way without the first dot, i.e. `:s#.\{64\}#&\r#g` since applied only to the current line in both cases. For the file with several long lines add `%` before the substitution command, i.e. `:%s#.\{64\}#&\r#g`

Answer (score 4):

```
Qa64l<enter>q16@a:w
```

This will record a macro to hit enter after moving to the right 64 times under the alias `a`, and will run that macro 16 times and save the file. Should do what you’re asking.

Comment: Another way to use macro (without entering in Ex mode): `qq64la<ENTER><ESC>q99@q`, where you should press the keys Enter and Esc.

Answer (score 4):

```
:set textwidth=64
gqgq
:set textwidth=0
```

It sets the limit to the maximum line length, reindents current line, and returns the limit back to the default value (I assume you use the default value)

Comment: I think it will work only for a text with spaces, which is not the case.